# Views not visible after adding them to relative layout programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am creating an activity to show timetable. I have a list of lectures, and the respective day and duration of each lecture. I am trying to inflate a compound view from a layout xml file, and then adding the inflated view to one of the relative layouts in an arraylist, where one element of the arraylist represents one column or a day.
days is an arraylist of relativelayouts. The below function is a member of the activity, and is the logic to add the lectures. According to the length of the lecture, I adjust the height with ViewGroup LayoutParams for the card inside the view, and then add the view in relative layout with relative layout params. But the views do not show up.

Edit : The Code is working fine, The arraylist of the model class was a problem.

[image: Screenshot of the activity]

```
private void addTimeTableViews(){
    for (LectureModel lecture : lectures) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        int currentDay = lecture.getDayOfTheWeek();
        RelativeLayout layout = days.get(currentDay);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_tt_box, layout);
        int boxHeight = getTimeDifference(lecture.getStartTime(),lecture.getEndTime());

        //to adjust height of the card according to length of lecture
        MaterialCardView card = view.findViewById(R.id.tt_box_card);
        int cardWidth = card.getLayoutParams().width;
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams cardParams = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(cardWidth, boxHeight - 4);
        card.setLayoutParams(cardParams);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        params.topMargin = getTimeInMinutes(lecture.getStartTime());

        layout.addView(view, params);
    }
}
```

Comment: Any chance `RelativeLayout layout = days.get(currentDay);` is not returning the view you think it is? Might be a View of screen or something?

Comment: I noticed the Model class was returning an empty list, so this loop did not happen altogether. This code is working fine